# Angularjs select2 Ajax binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, select

I am using AngularJs + Select2. I am trying to get the data from remote. Below is my code

HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-4 left">
  <input type="text" style="width:300px" ui-select2="multi" ng-model="multi2Value" multiple="multiple" />
 </div>
```

JS : **[UPDATED]**

```
 $scope.multi = {
            ajax: {
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                url: "http://localhost:63591/Lookup?lookup=Lookup&key=acc",
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {}; 
                },
                results: function (data, page) {             
                    console.log(data);
                    return {results: data.LookupValue};
                }
            }
```

And my response will be

```
{ "LookupValue" : [ "AAAA","BBBB","CCC" ] }
```

But in the console i am seeing the response. But it is not loading into the select dropdown.

What went wrong in my code. Can anyone plz help me ? Thanks

Comment: just simply return data.lookupvalue rather than an object with result property. `return data.LookupValue;`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must your response save in some scope variable like `$scope.listLookup` and return it in your ajax, and after this step, try to bind it in HTML like:

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="multi2Value" data-placeholder="Pick a Lookup">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="lookup in listLookup " value="{{lookup.value}}">{{lookup.text}}</option>
</select>
```

where *lookup* is every item in your list if items of *listLookup*, and *value* and *text* are some dummy properties of lookup...

Take look on [this article](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2#working-with-dynamic-options), hope that you understand the idea.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
return {results: data};
```

use

```
 return {results: data.LookupValue};
```

It might be either array of primitive types

```
[string,string,string]
```

or array of objects

```
[{},{},{}]
```

as well as :

```
data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term, //search term
                page: page // page number
            };
        },
```